# Table Splitting with Entity Framework Core. Flatten Table to Master-Detail

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, entity-framework

I want to put this flatten table into a master-detail hierarchy on class level

```
| Type | DateTime   | Value |
-----------------------------
| 4711 | 2018-01-01 |  0.7  |
| 4711 | 2018-01-02 |  0.8  |
| 4711 | 2018-01-03 |  0.9  |
| 4711 | 2018-01-04 |  1.0  |
| 4712 | 2018-01-01 |  3.2  |
| 4712 | 2018-01-02 |  2.7  |
| 4712 | 2018-01-03 |  5.6  |
| 4712 | 2018-01-04 |  1.9  |
```

**class-structure**

```
[Table("TypeValues")]
public class TypeMaster
{
    [Column("Type")]
    public int Type { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Type")]
    public virtual ICollection<TypeValue> Values { get; set; }
}

[Table("TypeValues")]
public class TypeValue
{
    [Column("DateTime")]
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

    [Column("Value")]
    public float? Value { get; set; }

    public TypeMaster Index { get; set; }
}
```

I already tried several variations between composite keys based of type and datetime, but everytime there is a new challange which prevents me from finishing this simple task. I have no idea anymore.

At the end I don't want to have redundant data like the type. I want the data grouped by that type.

```
{
  "Result": [
    {
      "Type": "4711",
      "Values": [
        {
          "TimeStamp": "2018-01-01",
          "Value": "0.7"
        },
        {
          "TimeStamp": "2018-01-02",
          "Value": "0.8"
        },
        {
          "TimeStamp": "2018-01-03",
          "Value": "0.9"
        },
        {
          "TimeStamp": "2018-01-04",
          "Value": "1.0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Type": "4712",
      "Values": [
        {
          "TimeStamp": "2018-01-01",
          "Value": "3.2"
        },
        {
          "TimeStamp": "2018-01-02",
          "Value": "2.7"
        },
        {
          "TimeStamp": "2018-01-03",
          "Value": "5.6"
        },
        {
          "TimeStamp": "2018-01-04",
          "Value": "1.9"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

## **Update**

To make this clear. I need a solution where I can forward the IQueryable to following services. The solution is not to manually group the data and than progress with a List<>.

So I need to solve this on model-level.

Comment: just use `GroupBy(x=>x.Type)` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Table splitting can't be used to normalize a poorly normalized data model.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that this is not possible. I need to do this by designing the classes and using the ModelBuilder

Comment: @GertArnold: okay what are my other options?

Comment: @masterchris_99 Table splitting is for one-to-one relationships. Your **only** option is to use query (`GroupBy`). You can't solve it at model level.

Comment: if you can't use .GroupBy, you'll need intermediate classes mapped to the db table and do the conversion in memory.

Comment: I don't see what's the problem of using `GroupBy` + `Select` transformation. It's still `IQueryable<T>` and can be further filtered, paged etc w/o loading the whole set in memory.

Answer (score -1):

Will this code work?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication86
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("DateTime", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(float));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4711, DateTime.Parse("2018-01-01"), 0.7 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4711, DateTime.Parse("2018-01-02"), 0.8 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4711, DateTime.Parse("2018-01-03"), 0.9 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4711, DateTime.Parse("2018-01-04"), 1.0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4712, DateTime.Parse("2018-01-01"), 3.2 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4712, DateTime.Parse("2018-01-02"), 2.7 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4712, DateTime.Parse("2018-01-03"), 5.6 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {4712, DateTime.Parse("2018-01-04"), 1.9 });

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("Type")).ToList();

            List<TypeMaster> data = (from g in groups
                                     select new { grp = new TypeMaster() { Type = g.Key }, rows = g })
                       .Select(x => new TypeMaster() {
                           Type = x.grp.Type,
                           Values = x.grp.Values = x.rows.Select(y => new TypeValue() {
                                   TimeStamp = y.Field<DateTime>("DateTime"),
                                   Value = y.Field<float>("Value"),
                                   Index = x.grp
                               }).ToList()
                       }).ToList();


         }

    }

    [Table("TypeValues")]
    public class TypeMaster
    {
        [Column("Type")]
        public int Type { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Type")]
        public virtual ICollection<TypeValue> Values { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("TypeValues")]
    public class TypeValue
    {
        [Column("DateTime")]
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

        [Column("Value")]
        public float? Value { get; set; }

        public TypeMaster Index { get; set; }
    }




}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Entity Framework. This is a simple Group By. I need to return the IQueryable. In your case the SQL statement is executed, converted into a list and then returned. So all further filter will be executed on the data already loaded into memory

Comment: You would just have to turn my code into an ObjectQuery.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546158.aspx

Comment: @jdweng Why do you answer a question by asking another question, followed by unexplained code? Future readers won't take the effort to dig into the code and find the relevant part that answers the question. That's why "try this"-answers (which this is in fact) aren't very useful. It's better to highlight the essence of the answer. I think the essence is: project the grouping into a master class. And as Ivan says above, this could perfectly well be an `IQueryable` that can be extended further. I think the `DataTable` part is only confusing.

Comment: How can you test the code without inputs?  My solution is answering the OP question about "Flatten DataTable to Classes".  I don't have "Master-Detail" application and can't test with OPs Environment and that is why I said "TRY".  I do not know if the OP will need to make changes to work in his environment.